# Trouble with Anaconda after updating MacBook to macOS Catalina

Tags: python, macos, anaconda, macos-catalina

I recently updated my Macbook Pro to Catalina; however, after the installation, the system automatically created a folder containing files that couldn't be automatically transferred to the desired location after the update.

In this folder, I only found my anaconda3 directory. At the moment, the Anaconda Navigator Icon contains a question mark and I cannot run the conda command from Terminal, without it rising the error "command not found".

I tried moving my anaconda3 directory to my home directory and run the command:

```
MBPdiAlessandro:~ alessandro$ export PATH="/Users/alessandro/anaconda3/bin:$PATH"
MBPdiAlessandro:~ alessandro$ conda
-bash: /Users/alessandro/anaconda3/bin/conda: //anaconda3/bin/python: bad interpreter: No such file or directory
```

However, the above-mentioned error is reported. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Anaconda Recently cleared that this problem still needs to be fixed. For more info check https://www.anaconda.com/how-to-restore-anaconda-after-macos-catalina-update/